# Issue Testing after IdentityServer3 Deploy

Tags: identityserver3

After going through walkthroughs I had a test mvc app, test web api, and identityserver3 all working perfectly on my machine.  I deployed IdentityServer3 to our servers in AWS behind a load balancer.  I followed all the instructions in the Deployment wiki.  I am able to hit the .wellknown configuration fine after deployment from a browser on my machine.

I changed the authority url for the mvc and api test apps to point to the aws deployment.  Clients, Scopes, users, etc are all configured identically as they are hitting the same database as it was when running on local machine.

I can get an access token using RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync just fine so I think ids is installed fine.

However, both the API and the MVC app just trying to use implicit flow are now failing.  FOr instance, when I try to hit a mvc controller action marked with [Authorize] I get an error stating "An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set".

If I try to hit the webapi from the mvc app (both running locally on my machine) after a successful RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync call, I get the error "Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)." after what seems like a timeout.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found part of my issue.  I left off the https:// prefix of the PublicOrigin in ids deployment.  Implicit flow to get logged into mvc app is now working fine.

I still have a problem where the web api is not Authorizing the call to the api controller action.  Evidently it is failing while it is processing the [Authorize] attribute.  Any ideas on how to debug log what is going on under the covers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem.  When specifying PublicOrigin, it has to be a full URL and not just the domain.  I had left off https:// prefix.

The web api issue was related to connectivity to the identity server.  There was some incorrect proxy settings for the app.

Comment: That's what an Origin is.